# Distinct Case Statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to return either just a '1' or a '0' and not both as what's currenlty occuring in a Case statement. My current statement is as follows. If there were ANY O's under a name then i need that to show instead of a '1'. If there are no '0' then i'd like '1' to show. Thank you for any help.

```
SELECT Distinct Room,   
       Unit, 
       Number, 
      (LastN +', '+ FirstN) AS Name,   

   min( CASE WHEN Ques1_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN Ques2_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN Ques3_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN Ques4_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
             WHEN Ques6_Yes = '1' THEN '0'
             WHEN Name IS NULL THEN '-1'
        ELSE '1'
   END AS Direction

 FROM Customer_Service.dbo.Name 
WHERE Name = 'smiff, jess'
```

Now i'm wondering how to get this to work. Sorry i'm newer to sql

Comment: What does this query return?  How many records are in that table with that name?

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Comment: @Bracuk - it will return a '1' and a '0' in one column in two rows if the person had 1 or more '0 & 1's. There could be upto 9 rows per a name with multiple columns "Ques1_Yes to Ques6_Yes" containing either a '1' or '0'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this?

```
SELECT 
  min( CASE  WHEN Ques1_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
                 WHEN Ques2_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
                 WHEN Ques3_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
                 WHEN Ques4_Yes = '0' THEN '0'
                 WHEN Ques6_Yes = '1' THEN '0'
                 WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 'NULL'
    ELSE '1'
          END) AS Direction

 FROM Customer_Service.dbo.Name 
WHERE Name = 'smiff, jess'
```

Comment: Wow easy! This actually looks like it'll work for me. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this wont work as a Null cant compute through a Min. I need '1, 0, or a Null' to show. :/

Comment: That should work. Thank you. Please see above. I'm now trying to figure out how to get this to work.